How to get customer email from Stripe checkout.session.expired
For my website, I see a lot of checkout.session.expired events from a Payment Link. This likely means people were on the fence on making a purchase and decided eventually not to do so. I would like to follow up with a discount code to these people to convert to a sale.
Unfortunately, the customer fields from this event is completely empty. The below is what I see on the Stripe Workbench in viewing the details of a checkout.session.expired:
"customer": null,
"customer_creation": 
"if_required",
"customer_details": null,
"customer_email": null,
"expires_at": 1729207070,

Is there any way for me to retrieve the customer email to follow up?
Any help is appreciated.
Went through the event object in detail and am unable to find any relevant customer information.

If you are using Payment Links, a Checkout Session will be created every time a user open the Payment Link URL. If the user doesn't submit the form, the Checkout Session will automatically expire 24 hours later, which will trigger a checkout.session.expired event.
Since the user didn't submit the form, then there is no way to know their email, unless you collected it yourself before.
